# Fireabse Cloud Functions timestamp to 'MM,DD,YYYY'

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-functions

I use firebase functions . I want to get date after 30 day with MM-DD-YYYY format. I try import datepipe but ı get some error like this : Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.

index.ts:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction =
 functions.pubsub.schedule("every 5 minutes").onRun((context) => {
   const a = new Date();
   const targetDate = new Date().setDate(a.getDate()+30);
   console.log("Target Date"+targetDate);
   admin.database().ref("reservations/").update({zafer: "zafer5353"});
   return null;
 });
```

Console.log(targetDate) output is :1648669741663 How can ı convert it to MM-DD-YYYY

package.json in functions:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleDateString()` for your use-case.

Here are the options:

```
// formats below assume the local time zone of the locale;
// America/Los_Angeles for the US

// US English uses month-day-year order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
// → "12/20/2012"

// British English uses day-month-year order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
// → "20/12/2012"

// Korean uses year-month-day order
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ko-KR'));
// → "2012. 12. 20."

// Event for Persian, It's hard to manually convert date to Solar Hijri
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('fa-IR'));
// → "۱۳۹۱/۹/۳۰"

// Arabic in most Arabic speaking countries uses real Arabic digits
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG'));
// → "٢٠‏/١٢‏/٢٠١٢"

// for Japanese, applications may want to use the Japanese calendar,
// where 2012 was the year 24 of the Heisei era
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ja-JP-u-ca-japanese'));
// → "24/12/20"

// when requesting a language that may not be supported, such as
// Balinese, include a fallback language, in this case Indonesian
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString(['ban', 'id']));
// → "20/12/2012"
```

For reference, here's the full code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction =
 functions.pubsub.schedule("every 5 minutes").onRun((context) => {
   const a = new Date();
   const targetDate = new Date().setDate(a.getDate() + 30);
   const targetDateFormat = new Date(targetDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
     year: "numeric",
     month: "2-digit",
     day: "2-digit"
   });
   console.log("Target Date: " + targetDateFormat);

   admin.database().ref("reservations/").update({zafer: "zafer5353"});
   return null;
 });
```

You can also specify the year, month and date format. You may also refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for more information.

You could also use `date` objects. We can call any of the getters listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get that value and build out the desired string:

```
const curr_date = ("0" + new Date(targetDate).getDate()).slice(-2);
//We add +1 because Jan is indexed at 0 instead of 1
const curr_month = ("0" + (new Date(targetDate).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
const curr_year = new Date(targetDate).getFullYear();

// Outputs 03-31-2022
console.log(curr_month + "-" + curr_date + "-" + curr_year);
```